# Get previous URL path in PHP

Tags: php, http, url, referrer

I've tried this one
`<?php $previous_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>`

and the result is `http://localhost/index.php`

how can i get only `index.php`

Comment: `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH)`

Comment: @Ja͢ck That's not what the OP specified.

Comment: Trimming leading slash is left as reader's exercise, otherwise I would've written an answer; in any case, it's not even clear what would need to be returned if there's more to the path

Comment: @Ja͢ck True about unclarity. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$previous_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($previous_page);
$result = $path_parts['basename']; //index.php
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php